# How to setup VSCode to use local ESLint over the global configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

If I have a global ESLint configuration and a local one, I want to automatically use the local lint configuration over the global one.

Otherwise, I want to use the global config.

Answer (score 1):

Use `root: true` in your local eslint configuration file. This is described in [Cascading and Hierarchy](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#cascading-and-hierarchy):

> The configuration cascade works based on the location of the file being linted. If there is an `.eslintrc` file in the same directory as the file being linted, then that configuration takes precedence. ESLint then searches up the directory structure, merging any `.eslintrc` files it finds along the way until reaching either an `.eslintrc` file with `root: true` or the root directory.
>
> ...
>
> By default, ESLint looks for configuration files in all parent folders up to the root directory. This can be useful if you want all of your projects to follow a certain convention, but can sometimes lead to unexpected results. To limit ESLint to a specific project, place `"root": true` inside the `.eslintrc.*` file or `eslintConfig` field of the `package.json` file or in the `.eslintrc.*` file at your project’s root level. ESLint stops looking in parent folders once it finds a configuration with `"root": true`.